# How do I stop noise coming from the rest of the house?

Tags: doors, sound-proofing, noise

I just moved in a studio that was built as an annex to a house where more people live. There's this door from my studio to the rest of the house and every time someone goes downstairs, shuts a door, or talks near the door, I hear everything.

Is there a way of improving sound isolation apart from changing the door (it's a rental so wouldn't be that easy). Would cork for the entire door plus weather sealing work?

Images:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you considered mentioning this to your landlord in a nice way? "Hey, home owner, just thought I'd let you know that I can hear all your conversations right through this door. Could we work on some sound proofing, or would you consider trying to be more quiet near here?"Amazing how asking nicely can sometimes get things fixed with minimal effort on your part.

Comment: Is that an exposed OSB floor? I see some gloss in your second image. Is there some sort of clear coat on it? Before assuming that all of the noise is coming through the door, I would weather seal the door and experiment with my heaviest blanket for testing.

Comment: @popham that's an OSB floor, yes. Do you mean that the floor could be the cause here?

Comment: Just an off-topic observation. Apologies for the distraction. If you don't mind my asking, how difficult is it to clean? That coating looks thick enough (maybe an epoxy coating) that it might actually be nice. On-topic, take the low-hanging fruit first. Weather stripping is step #1. And some strike plates have an adjustable little tongue in there that you can bend to close the door tighter to its stop trim.

Comment: @popham no worries, haha, I was just a bit confused. It's a thick coat yes, and recently applied as I just moved in and it still smells. It's quite nice and comfortable, easy to vacuum. Only thing is that it's hard to see how dirty it is. Thanks for the tips about the door, will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sound transmission happens primarily through two paths:

- Transmission through surfaces. In this case, lots of sound is likely coming through the glass in your door. A dense wood door will transmit much less sound than a glass door.
- Transmission through air. Given your pictures, some sound will be coming via the leak around the edge of the door. Anywhere air can leak, sound can leak.

The ideal case (as you have identified) is to replace the door with a solid door, ideally one with acoustic design, a very tightly fitting gasket all the way around the edge and that is properly sealed to the wall around the exterior of the frame. This door and frame setup would be likely to cost 5X-10X as much as a basic door.

Of course, as you say this is a rental, so let's take that option off the table. Thinking about what our sound transmission paths above, there's a few low cost and low impact improvements you can do. Examples:

- Make sure around the edge of the door where it closes is well sealed. A soft foam or rubber self-adhesive weatherstripping can work here. You'll know you have it about right when the door is somewhat difficult to fully close. To test, put a piece of paper in the door when you're closing it. Anywhere you can easily pull the paper out of the closed door edge is not sealed enough. Doing this across the bottom will likely require a specialized door seal and possibly modification of the sill. You might skip the bottom for that reason. Be aware that if you have a forced air heating system, it may depend on air moving around the door for air return, and sealing the door will substantially reduce the airflow from any vents in the space.
- Add sound absorption in front of the windows on the door. Cork is an OK option. Other options such as dense acoustic foam, rockwool wrapped in fabric, mass loaded vinyl, rigid fiberglass in fabric, etc can provide better results than cork. Whatever you use, you'll want as thick of a piece of it as you can make work with the door and handle.
- Add sound absorption in front of the door itself. A heavy drape with high fullness can absorb a few dB of sound.

Comment: Could get a slab of pink insulating foam and tape that over the door as "relatively inexpensive and easy."  Would still need to seal around door edges, of course.

Comment: If you're talking pink XPS foam, it's pretty useless for absorbing sound. It's too rigid. Acoustic foam is dense and typically open-celled.

Comment: @KMJ great and detailed answer. I bought the weatherstrip and will apply now. Will be getting an alternative to the cork as you mentioned. Thanks!